# working with list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, adapter

I've been trying to make a ListView appear on the screen, I must be missing something cause it just don't work.
The code is very simple, taking out data from DB and making a string out of it later comes the adapter and list settings.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_singles);
    db = new DbHelper(ViewSinglesAndAdd.this);
    db.open();
    this.all = db.getAllSingle();
    db.close();
    showList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSingles);
    if (all == null)
        Toast.makeText(ViewSinglesAndAdd.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    if (all != null) {
        String[] select = new String[all.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
            select[i] = all.elementAt(i).getPerson().toString();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                ViewSinglesAndAdd.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, select);
        showList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        showList.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

Comment: What is `all` stands for?

Comment: Would mind showing the layout file too?

Answer (score 1):

If `all` stands for your String `ArrayList` then you need to change

```
   select[i] = all.elementAt(i).getPerson().toString();
```

to

```
   select[i] = all.get(i).getPerson();
```